# Cannot get data from Firestore with date range

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a Firebase collection like this:

[image]

I am trying to get the data that has the date range condition using this code:

**ticket-form.html.ts**

```
<form
    [formGroup]="form2"
    #fd2="ngForm"
    class="form"
    (submit)="onSubmmitDates(form2.value, fd2)">
    <div class="form__article">
      <h3>Ticket Data</h3>

      <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input
            class="mdl-textfield__input"
            type="date"
            id="dateFrom"
            formControlName="dateFrom"
          />
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="dateFrom">Date From</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input
            class="mdl-textfield__input"
            type="date"
            id="dateTo"
            formControlName="dateTo"
          />
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="dateTo">Date To</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form__action">
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <button
        id="submit_button"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**ticket-form.component.ts**

```
onSubmmitDates(value: any) {
    this.ts.getSpecificTicket(value.dateFrom, value.dateTo).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.ticketsList = res.map(item => {
          return {
            ...item.payload.doc.data(),
          };
        });
        console.log(this.ticketsList);
      }
    );
    // const x = this.ts.getSpecificTicket(value.dateFrom, value.dateTo);
}

onGetAll() {
    this.ts.getAll().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.ticketsList = res.map(item => {
          return {
            ...item.payload.doc.data(),
          };
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

**ticket.service.ts**

```
private ticketList: AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
) { }

// Parameters is from the 2 date pickers in the html
getSpecificTicket(dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date): any {
    let df: any = new Date(dateFrom);
    df = df.getTime();
    let dt: any = new Date(dateTo);
    dt = dt.getTime();
    return this.firestore.collection('/tickets', ref => ref.where('issuedOn', '>', df).where('issuedOn', '<', dt)).snapshotChanges();
}

getAll() {
   return this.firestore.collection('tickets').snapshotChanges();
}
```

When I run the `onGetAll()` I get all the data but if I use the `onSubmmitDates(.., ...)`, I don't get any results just a blank array "[]".

> dateFrom: "2019-11-19"
>
> dateTo: "2019-11-20"
>
> On conversion to time stamp,
>
> df: 1574121600000
>
> dt: 1574208000000

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly how you are invoking the function, including the exact values of the parameters you're passing to it.  We should be able to trace through the execution of the function with all values known.

Comment: @DougStevenson Pleas see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't see what dates you're passing to getSpecificTicket.  Everything is still just variables.  For all I know, you're passing invalid dates, or dates that don't match any documents.  Help us understand what you're passing, and why you should be receiving any documents in the results.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please see my edit. Hope that makes it clear. Thank you.

Comment: Which documents are you expecting to be returned using that date range?  Have you tried other date ranges?

Comment: All documenta that have a timestamp of nov 19 - 20, 2019. Basically all the docs. All if it have issuedOn on Nov. 19, 2019. I should have three results Sir.

Comment: Have you tried a different date range?  What if you extended the range one day in both directions?  Or a year in both directions?

Comment: Dates are saved as UTC string in firebase. The example dates that you have given at the end of your question, shows these UTC datetime strings: **dateFrom =** `19 Nov 2019 00:00:00 UTC` and **dateTo =** `20 Nov 2019 00:00:00 UTC`. But the example data you have shown in Firebase Console shows "20 Nov 14:11:11 UTC+8" which is obviously after your dateTo and dateFrom.

Comment: @terahertz Dates are not stored as strings in Firestore.  They are similar to the Timestamp data type provided by the SDKs and have integer components for seconds and nanoseconds.

Comment: Hi @Ibanez1408, are you still facing this issue or did you already resolve it? I will wait for your reply.

Comment: @Silopis I just separated my Date and Time in Firestore.